# How to develop on an existing npm package against real code?

Tags: npm, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, node-modules, package.json

I'd like to contribute a change to Karma. So I've cloned the repo and `npm install`ed everything

The problem is, I don't know how to actually run my local version against real code, as I would use it in real life. For example, in a real project, I would set up `karma.conf.js`, and launch by running `karma`. How do I do this but with the local `karma` project that I am modifying?

http://karma-runner.github.io/latest/dev/making-changes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your real project, instead of installing karma using `npm install karma --save-dev` as you would usually do, you need to install it from the development directory like `npm install /path/to/dev/karma --save-dev`.

Then when in your project, the `karma` commands should point to your dev version.

(You might need to remove the karma installed from node_modules before you install your dev version)